# Riemann rearrangement of series applies here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Imagine the next identities that holds simultaneously for a given real positive $x_0$

$$A(x_0)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^n}{n!}a_n = 0$$
$$A(-x_0)= 0$$

It is obvious to me the next identities and reasoning can follow, basically splitting the even powers to one side, and the odd powers to the other:

$$A(x_0)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^{2n}}{(2n)!}a_{2n} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}a_{2n+1} = 0$$
$$A(-x_0)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^{2n}}{(2n)!}a_{2n} - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}a_{2n+1} = 0$$

So can I conclude then that necessarily: 
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^{2n}}{(2n)!}a_{2n} =0$$ 
and
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}a_{2n+1} = 0$$
?

I totally understand from Riemann rearrangement theorem of conditionally convergent series and the way the series convergence is calculated yields to getting different results, arbitrary different results, based on the permutation put in place, basically because the partial summation is artificially manipulated.

However it is also true that if we had the capacity to expand the infinite serie, the commutative property applies indefinitely.

What are your thoughts ? Do you find a better way or reference to prove on a similar case, that odd an even series should be simultaneously $0$?

Comment: Obviously  $a_n$ sign may change with $n$

Comment: If the radius of convergence is larger than $|x_0|$ then the convergence of the series is absolute at $x_0$ and you can just reorder the series.

Assume now that the radius of convergence is $|x_0|$.
If the $a_n$ are real, then by Abel's theorem the limits $A(\pm x)\to0$ hold when $x\to x_0$ radially.

This means that $E(x)=\frac{A(x)+A(-x)}{2}\to0$ when $x\to x_0$ radially.
**If in addition we know** that $a_{2n}/(2n)!=O(1/2n)$ then, by Littlewoods-Tauber's theorem the series of $E(x)$ converges at $x_0$.